# How to save photos and videos from iPhone with exif time data?

Tags: iphone, macos, photo

I want to get my photos and videos from iPhone on my laptop.
I realized, that I am not able to save with on Mac with Photos app (it adds a sequentially name to the photo..)
and with iCloud there is no option to download all photos together. (Apple-prison).

Answer (score 0):

I found the way after a lot of research and probation:

Workaround 1 - iPhone side
On iPhone with Dropbox app you can upload photos and videos to the cloud, and then you can download them anywhere you wish (even with the free version).
Dropbox is clever enough (not like Mac's Photos app...), to use camera time for naming. So your file names will be a timestamp when you have taken the picture OR video AKA Exif data).

Workaround 2 - desktop machine side
You can use Photos app (on Macbooks), because with cable it is obviously faster than uploading to Dropbox through wifi.
But... Photos app is so "old-school", that when you export photos, it will not use your Exif data as filenames, it will create a sequence, like IMG_6033.mov rather..
images, you can use Exif-renamer app (available in the app-store).
It is free, and it can rename all images in a folder to the timestamp from Exif data.
Unfortunately, it can not rename videos..

https://apps.apple.com/us/app/rename-with-exif/id1469032019?mt=12

Answer (score 0):

This is work on iOS 17 & current Google Photo

1. Copy photos from iOS Internal Storage to PC
2. Copy to Android Phone
3. Backup / Sync by Google Photo to Googl Server
4. Google Photo save iOS's exif data (date/time/gps/camera config)